# What is happening in the Curly Braces

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, curly-braces

As I know, `}` contains in actual some operation like destroying the stack allocated objects because when some error is happening in the destructor of an object, VS.NET point me to the closing of the Curly Braces and even you can step into it using `F11` and see what is happening in the destructors that have been called. However, I have notice that the `{` is also an operation and if I try to step into it using `F11`, VS.NET tell me that it need `memset.asm` file in order to contiune debugin.

What is really happening inside `{`?

Comment: Actually the curly braces themselves are not operators, they "contain" no code. It's the compiler that adds code then a scope begins and ends, but it's not really related to the braces (except they show where scopes begin and end). When you step into e.g. destructors, it code that is inserted after your code but before the actual end of the scope. That the cursor ends up on the closing brace is because the debugger doesn't have any other location information.

Comment: I got it thanks. So, my question should be what is happening before my code in the beginning of a scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curly braces establish scope and lifetime.  Objects created within a pair of curly braces are not accessible outside of them.  They are not code; but, since the objects will likely be freed when you exit them, the compiler may produce code as a result of the closing curly brace.

Regarding stepping into the opening curly brace, you are actually stepping into the first executable line of code within the curly brace.  That line of code would explain why the debugger is trying to step into memset.asm.

Comment: Thanks, but this line that is trying to step into memset.asm was not written by me. as @jachim stated in his comment, this line was produced by the compiler and my question is about what is happening there.

Comment: There must be something within the curly braces.  Whatever is there must be calling memset.  Note that stepping into a native language statement in C++ can result in things like this because you are trying to step into the code that the code the compiler itself is generating.  Ex: If you are declaring an array, the compiler may be using memset to clear memory.  This is very compiler specific.